# selected option is not unselected while clicking on the element twice

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, jquery-select2

select2 ajax select elements clicking once and unselect element clicking twice. This is by default .but in my case element is selecting by one click but not unselecting clicking twice. what is the problem here

views.py

```
def search(request):
    query=request.GET.get("q")
    print(query)
    vid=Video.objects.filter(tags__name__icontains=query).order_by("name").distinct()  
    print(vid)
    vid_list=\[{'id':k.id,"name":k.name,"tags":','.join(k.tags.names())} for k in vid\]

    print(type(vid_list))
    return JsonResponse(vid_list,safe=False)
```

home.html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Example of multiple select</label>
  <select class="form-control" multiple placeholder="Choose skills" id="some" required>
  
  </select>
</div>
```

scripts

```
<script>
  $("p").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:"{%url 'home' %}",
      success:function(data){
        alert("this is a ajax alert")
      }
    })
  
  })

  $("#some").select2({
    ajax:{
      url:"{% url 'search'%}",
      data: function(params){
        return{
          "q":params.term
        }
      },
      processResults:function(data){
        console.log(data)
        return{
          results:data.map(function(item){
            return{id:item.id,name:item.name,tags:item.tags} 
          })
          }
        },
        delay:250,
      cache:true,
      },
      




    minimumInputLength:1,
    closeOnSelect: false,
    allowClear:true,
    multiple:true,
    placeholder: "Search Video",
    templateResult:function(repo){
      console.log(repo)
      if (repo.loading) return repo.name;
      
      
      if (repo && !repo.selected){
        return`
        <span>
          ${repo.name}(${repo.tags})
        </span>
        `
      }
      
    },
    templateSelection:function(data){
      return`
      <span >
        ${data.name}
      </span>
      `
     
    
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
      return markup;
    },
  })
  
    


  </script>
```

Now i want to know what is the reason behind this .i mean why option is not unselecting when i click second time on the option

Comment: By default, when you have a multi-select, you need to CTRL + click to unselect. If you're not using a regular select, but a library (for example, select2), please post the relevant code. It would help if you could create a jsfiddle / codepen / codebox / jsbin of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Just the front end. You can simulate the option generation from AJAX with an API, like [this one](https://pokeapi.co/), or [this one](https://covidtracking.com/data/api/version-2) (or any other public API service you want).

Comment: when i am working with some manual data using select2 and ajax the selecting and unselecting is working good but in case of data from database which are coming up dynamically ,this time selected clicking once and unselected clicking twice is not working

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Also, if the data you're getting from the database is not sensitive, could you post the contents of your AJAX response? If it is sensitive data (for example, people's emails, phone numbers, etc), could you replace it with something else, and then post it in your question? This is just so we can test the stuff, and see what's causing the problem.